# Unexpected $end error

Tags: php

keep getting the $end error on the code below. I have cleared some of the errors by using codepad, but now l am stuck. I know it has something to do with colons and semi- colons but l cant seem to know where the problem is. HELP

```
<?php

$dbName="";
$dbUsername="";
$dbPassword="";

$fromPC=$_POST['fromPC'];
$toPC=$_POST['toPC'];


//

function getDistance($lat1, $long1, $lat2, $long2, $unit)
{

  if($unit=="miles"){
      $earth = 3960; //miles
  }else{
     $earth = 6371; //kilometres
  }

    //From co-ordinates
    $lat1 = deg2rad($lat1);
    $long1= deg2rad($long1);

    //To co-ordinates
    $lat2 = deg2rad($lat2);
    $long2= deg2rad($long2);

    // The Haversine Formula
    $dlong=$long2-$long1;
    $dlat=$lat2-$lat1;

    $sinlat=sin($dlat/2);
    $sinlong=sin($dlong/2);

    $a=($sinlat*$sinlat)+cos($lat1)*cos($lat2)*($sinlong*$sinlong);

    $c=2*asin(min(1,sqrt($a)));



$d=round($earth*$c);

    return $d;
}




if( (!empty($fromPC)) && (!empty($toPC)) )
{
    mysql_connect("********",$dbUsername,$dbPassword);
    @mysql_select_db($dbName) or die( "Unable to select database");

  // basic cleaning of input
    $firstPC = strtoupper(preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/","", ));
    $secondPC = strtoupper(preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/","", ));

    // get first details
    $query = 'SELECT `latitude`, `longitude` FROM `uk_postcodes` WHERE `postcode`="'.$firstPC.'";';
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $first = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    $checkFirst=mysql_num_rows($result);

  // get second details
    $query = 'SELECT `latitude`, `longitude` FROM `uk_postcodes` WHERE 

`postcode`="'.$secondPC.'";';
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $second = mysql_fetch_row($result);
  $checkSecond=mysql_num_rows($result);

  // ensure there were results to calculate with
  if( ($checkFirst<1) || ($checkSecond<1) ){
      $outputResults="Unrecognised postcode entered.";
  }else{
        $distance = getDistance($first[0], $first[1], $second[0], $second[1], "miles");
        $outputResults = "The distance between postcode: $firstPC and postcode: $secondPC is ".$distance." miles.";
  }

  // always close your connections !!
    mysql_close();
}

?>


<?=$outputResults?>
```

Comment: Check this: http://cs.wellesley.edu/~cs111/review_materials/conditionals.html

Comment: No idea what you're question actually is.  That's why your getting down votes.  Try rephrasing what your problem is and possibly paste your actual error in the question as well

Comment: What I notice right away is that a) you have included a ; at the end of your sql queries, b) you are using the old mysql drivers instead of mysqli where you can pass the values through parameters, c) you have included the full access credentials into your database in the question, and d) those two selects could be easily written as one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse error, This

```
$firstPC = strtoupper(preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/","", ));
    $secondPC = strtoupper(preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/","", ));
```

Should be

```
$firstPC = strtoupper(preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/","","Any String"));
    $secondPC = strtoupper(preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/","","Any String" ));
```